# How to split a string in two substrings of same length using bash?

Tags: bash, string

I would like to split a string into two halves and print them sequentially. For example:

```
abcdef
```

into

```
abc
def
```

Is there a simple way to do it, or it needs some string processing?

Comment: How do you have the incoming string? Variable? Stdin? Other?

Comment: In a variable. It doesn't really matter, as anything can be worked out (stdin input can be put in a variable).

Comment: It matters for efficiency, especially if it can be possibly-gigantic.  And also for convenience.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and [shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion):

The first half of the variable will be:

```
${var:0:${#var}/2}
```

The second half of the variable will be:

```
${var:${#var}/2}
```

---

so you could use:

```
printf '%s\n' "${var:0:${#var}/2}" "${var:${#var}/2}"
```

---

You could also use the following awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++)printf $i}{printf "\n"}{for(i=NF/2+1;i<=NF;i++){printf $i}{printf "\n"}}'
```

---

```
$ echo abcdef | awk 'BEGIN{FS=""}{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++)printf $i}{printf "\n"}{for(i=NF/2+1;i<=NF;i++){printf $i}{printf "\n"}}'
abc
def
```

Comment: concise and elegant solution.

Comment: You can get rid of the `$((...))`; the `off` and `len` part of the `${var:off:len}` substitution are already evaluated as arithmetic expressions. Example: `foo=01234567; echo "${foo:0:${#foo}/2} ${foo:${#foo}/2}"`. That's documented, and it's the same in `zsh` and `ksh93` as in bash.

Comment: Note: If the length of the string is odd, this will still split it into two parts, but the second will be a character longer.

Answer (score 9):

Using `split`, here strings and command substitution:

```
var=abcdef
printf '%s\n' "$(split -n1/2 <<<$var)" "$(split -n2/2 <<<$var)"
```

Answer (score 7):

Another `awk` script can be:

```
echo abcdef | awk '{print substr($0,1,length/2); print substr($0,length/2+1)}'
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't work with mawk or busybox awk because of the syntax ambiguity of division `/` and the `/ERE/` operator, and the special case of  `()` being optional for `length` (still those implementations are not POSIX compliant in that case). Using `length()` or `length($0)` here instead of `length` would help for those. You could also do `awk 'BEGIN{half = int(length(ARGV[1]) / 2); print substr(ARGV[1], 1, half) ORS substr(ARGV[1], half+1)}' abcdef` which would save the pipe and extra process and make it work even if the string contains newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3

```
s = input()  # Take one line of input from stdin.
x = len(s) // 2  # Get middle of string. "//" is floor division
print(s[:x], s[x:], sep="\n")  # Print "s" up to "x", then "s" past "x", joined on newlines.
```

For example,

```
$ echo abcdef | python3 -c 's = input(); x = len(s) // 2; print(s[:x], s[x:], sep="\n")'
abc
def
```

If the string length is not an even number, the second line will be longer. E.g.

```
$ echo abcdefg | python3 -c 's = input(); x= len(s) // 2; print(s[:x], s[x:], sep="\n")'
abc
defg
```